# Add different Content Views to a Content page (Rg.Popups) - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Popup page using Rg.Popups in Xamarin Forms. There are different variations of the popup in the application, and I would ideally want to use the same popup with different contents in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="CustomKeyboard.Controls.CustomPopup"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomKeyboard.Controls;assembly=CustomKeyboard"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
 <StackLayout 
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    BackgroundColor = "#00000000"
    Padding="20, 0, 20, 0">
    <Frame CornerRadius = "8"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
       <local:Content1 />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

The  is a content view and its static. I would need to content View to be dynamic.

So when I navigate to the CustomPopup, I should be able to specify which ContentView I need to use, and the popup need to render that specific content view. Appreciate if someone could suggest a neat way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with something like this and its works well for me.

I created the control just using c# (no xaml). But u could do that as well

```
public class PDTPopup : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public PDTPopup(ContentView view)
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame
        {
            CornerRadius = 8,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Content = view

        };
        this.Content = new Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00000000"),
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0),
            Children =
            {
                frame
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and then, where i need to call the popup. I do

```
public Command PopupCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () => {
                Content1Page view = new Content1Page();
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new CustomPopup(view));
            });
        }
    }
```